# Facebook, FBML: Is it possible to integrate application developed in php sdk with the Fans Page?

Tags: facebook, fbml

Is it possible to integrate application developed in php sdk with the Fans Page (Show application in Fans page)?

Please let me know the eg. how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Applications can be added as a tab on Fan Pages, you can't "integrate" it into the page.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to add applications as tab on Fan Pages.

Comment: First, the app has to be "enabled" to be added as a tab. There is a section in the app config for entering a "tab" URL. To actually add an app to a page, just go to the application's page (i.e. http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=103790709661573) and click on the "Add to My Page" link in the upper left.

Answer (score 0):

The "Facebook Integration" tab of your app config has a section to define this. You'll need to specify a URL beneath your app domain that contains the content to load. This tab must be FBML-compliant (though FB plans to migrate these to iFrames).

IMPORTANT: Facebook has eliminated Tabs on user profiles. They are now for Facebook Pages only.

Comment: Facebook is eliminating (in process) Profile Boxes, not Tabs. Tabs will be going away around the end of the year. It's all quite annoying.